# How to get Windows 10 to execute a shutdown script prior to the “closing X apps and restarting screen”?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, shutdown, reboot

The problem I have is that I have an application (steamVR) that refuses to shut down when it receives a shutdown signal. It instead brings up a popup "critical error" message and a second "are you sure you want to shut down message" that prevents the computer from shutting down. I thought doing a group policy to execute a script that runs a forced shutdown would work, but that doesn't get run until later in the shutdown process. I cannot install a third party application to solve this problem, and I don't want to write a custom "watcher" application to detect the shutdown signal just to kill this other application. I also am not allowed to change the registry to force a shutdown via the AllowBlockingAppsAtShutdown DWORD value.

Comment: Shut the game down first (close it) before shutting down the computer. I find closing all active apps prior to shutdown to be very helpful.

Comment: So you can't change the registry locally but you can change group-policy on the domain? What weird situation is that?

Comment: This computer is headless and the shutdown cannot require any user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I put the link of that file you need here (trust me I have nothing to do with people that I don't know)

the link : http://www.multcloud.com/share/5e1b7ad4-a1f8-4b18-9a55-0399426a48c9

You should just open link and right click on file and click on download.

Code added so link no longer needed

```
@echo off
color 0a
:CONFIRM
echo Do you really want to shutdown your PC? (only answer with yes/no or y/n
set /p shutdown=
if %shutdown%==yes goto 1
if %shutdown%==no goto 2
if %shutdown%==y goto 1
if %shutdown%==n goto 2
if NOT %shutdown%==yes goto CONFIRM
if NOT %shutdown%==no goto CONFIRM
:1
echo Your pc will shutdown in 10 seconds
timeout 10
shutdown.exe -s -t 00
:2
pause
exit
```

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: whats the links problem please explain easy

Comment: Include in your answer: the essential parts of the reference link as the answer can become invalid if the linked page change.

Comment: oh i didnt know that so what should i do or how can i make a better link

Comment: @NoobM You didn't read the site FAQ I presume. Please do so as soon as possible. Link only answers are not a good idea because stuff on the internet moves/disappears all the time making links invalid. Please put the full answer/steps to follow in the answer itself. You can edit your answer. There is markdown available to insert script-code.

Comment: Please explain what your solution is, not a link.  I don't just randomly download things from strangers.

Comment: ok i maded a batch file that shuttdown computer just that nothing else

Comment: but i say how you can do what i did

Comment: The provided link not only fails to be a meaningful answer to the question, the code contained within is riddled with poor syntax